# Understanding elm union types

Tags: elm, union-types

I am having some troubles wrapping my head around union types in elm. I understand the simple use case like

```
type Visibility = All | Active | Completed
```

So that means that the value of Visiblity can be All, Active or Completed. So far so good. Where i get confused however is

```
type Msg
   = OnFetchMails (WebData (List Mail))
   | OnFetchSmss (WebData (List SMS))
```

How should i interpret this? Does it mean Msg can be of the type function OnFetchMails that takes a type function WebData that takes a list of mail? Or how should i interpret this?
I don't think that `(WebData (List Mail))` is the payload?

Funny enough i can get it to work without understanding it

Answer (score 14):

When defining a union type, you list all the ways to construct a value of that type. In its simplest form, that definition looks like this:

```
type Visibility 
  = All 
  | Active 
  | Completed
```

As you've surmised, this declares the type `Visibility` and defines three values, all of type `Visibility`. The only way to construct a value of type `Visibility` is to use one of these three options. Because of that, we often call them "constructors."

Here is a slightly more complicated union type definition:

```
type TrainStatus
  = OnTime
  | Delayed Int
```

As you would expect, this defines two new "constructors," `OnTime` and `Delayed`. But look at their types:

```
OnTime  : TrainStatus
Delayed : Int -> TrainStatus
```

The `OnTime` constructor takes zero arguments, and so is simply a value; it is already a `TrainStatus`. But `Delayed` is declared as a one-argument constructor: it is a *function* that creates a new `TrainStatus` out of an `Int`. As such, `Delayed 5`, `Delayed 10`, and `Delayed 100` are all valid `TrainStatus` values. (We can interpret them as "delayed by 5 minutes" or something similar.)

A constructor can take multiple arguments; for instance, if we'd like to include, as a String, a reason for a delay:

```
type TrainStatus
  = OnTime
  | Delayed Int String

ts : TrainStatus
ts = Delayed 20 "The conductor took a short nap."
```

which defines `Delayed : Int -> String -> TrainStatus`.

If you're given a `TrainStatus`, you can extract the `Int` and `String` inside of it using pattern matching:

```
case ts of
  OnTime ->
    "Your train is on time!"

  Delayed minutes reason ->
    "Your train has been delayed by " ++ toString minutes ++ " because " ++ reason
```

Answer (score 7):

Actually, yes, you can think of it as a payload that goes along with each branch.

```
type Msg
    = OnFetchMails (WebData (List Mail))
    | OnFetchSmss (WebData (List SMS))
```

Means that a value of type `Msg` can be either `OnFetchMails`, which will have some value of type `WebData (List Mail)` to go with it; or it can be `OnFetchSmss` with a `WebData (List SMS)` accompanying it.

They're sometimes called *tagged unions*, as they act a lot like a C-style `union` construct bundled up with a *tag* value which says which option in the union is the currently valid one (and in fact many languages with this kind of structure in do implement them that way).

They could also be modelled as a series of subclasses of an abstract base `Msg` type, adding storage for their payloads in each subclass and requiring the payloads to be provided as constructor parameters.